# Counting result in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have query in SQL Server 2012 to view user's division in my company.

```
SELECT mdl_user_info_data.data
FROM 
    dbo.mdl_user, 
    dbo.mdl_course, 
    dbo.mdl_user_enrolments, 
    dbo.mdl_enrol, 
    dbo.mdl_course_categories,
    dbo.mdl_user_info_data
WHERE 
    mdl_course.id = mdl_enrol.courseid AND 
    mdl_enrol.id = mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid AND 
    mdl_user_enrolments.userid = mdl_user.id AND 
    mdl_course.category = mdl_course_categories.id AND 
    mdl_course.id = 3 and
    mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 3 and
    mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
```

And the result from my query is:

```
|data|
|CIS|
|CIS|
|TOP|
```

But I want is like this:

```
|DATA| TOTAL |
|CIS | 2 |
|TOP | 1 |
```

can somebody help me? anyway thanks.

my mdl_user_info_data properties :

```
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[userid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[fieldid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[data] [ntext] NOT NULL,
[dataformat] [smallint] NOT NULL,
```

some row from mdl_user_info_data : 
id     userid  fieldid  data   dataformat 
3   3   3   CIS 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT id.data, COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.mdl_user u
JOIN dbo.mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN dbo.mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN dbo.mdl_course c ON c.id = e.courseid
--JOIN dbo.mdl_course_categories cc ON c.category = cc.id
JOIN dbo.mdl_user_info_data id ON u.id = id.userid
WHERE c.id = 3
     AND id.fieldid = 3
GROUP BY id.data
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT t.data, Total = COUNT(1) 
FROM (
     SELECT data = CAST(id.data AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM dbo.mdl_user u
     JOIN dbo.mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
     JOIN dbo.mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
     JOIN dbo.mdl_course c ON c.id = e.courseid
     --JOIN dbo.mdl_course_categories cc ON c.category = cc.id
     JOIN dbo.mdl_user_info_data id ON u.id = id.userid
     WHERE c.id = 3
          AND id.fieldid = 3
) t
GROUP BY t.data
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but your code doesn't work to, sorry about that. this is an error :
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Sorry, but why you are using `ntext`? This datatype is deprecated. Try to change datatype to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or something similar.

Comment: i didn't create that database, database is automatically created by moodle system. i recently working on project that was used CMS moodle.

Comment: You're welcome @user1533670. Also please read this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `group by` clause

```
SELECT mdl_user_info_data.data,count(1) as Total
FROM dbo.mdl_user, 
     dbo.mdl_course, 
     dbo.mdl_user_enrolments, 
     dbo.mdl_enrol, 
     dbo.mdl_course_categories,
     dbo.mdl_user_info_data
WHERE mdl_course.id = mdl_enrol.courseid AND 
      mdl_enrol.id = mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid AND 
      mdl_user_enrolments.userid = mdl_user.id AND 
      mdl_course.category = mdl_course_categories.id AND 
      mdl_course.id = 3 and
      mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 3 and
      mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
group by 
      mdl_user_info_data.data
```

but please consider below solution

```
SELECT muid.data,count(1) as Total
FROM dbo.mdl_user mu, 
     dbo.mdl_course mc, 
     dbo.mdl_user_enrolments mue, 
     dbo.mdl_enrol me, 
     dbo.mdl_course_categories mcc,
     dbo.mdl_user_info_data muid
WHERE mc.id = me.courseid AND 
      me.id = mue.enrolid AND 
      mue.userid = mu.id AND 
      mc.category = mcc.id AND 
      mc.id = 3 and
      muid.fieldid = 3 and
      mu.id = muid.userid
group by muid.data
```

In the above example I've added aliases to columns. It's good practice to use them because the code is more readable.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it produce error like this :
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: in second code, it still produce error, here it is :
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: @user1533670 Can you describe `mdl_user_info_data` table ?